# my app crashes when I swipe from one fragment to another (error: canScrollHorizontally()' on a null object reference)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I've been trying to resolve this problem but with no result. My app is made up of 4 fragments, the second one with a recycler view. When I swipe from the first to the second my app instantly crashes. And in the logCat this error appears:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.canScrollHorizontally()' on a null object reference at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView.java:2022)

Here's my code for the main activity:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        toolbar.setTitle("Quick!");
    }
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    fragmentList.add(HomeFragment.getInstance(0));
    fragmentList.add(KartFragment.getInstance(1));
    fragmentList.add(FavouriteFragment.getInstance(2));
    fragmentList.add(ScannerFrag.getInstance(3));


    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.Pager);
    pager.setAdapter(new myPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    tab = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.SlidingTab);
    tab.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.accentColor);
        }
    });
    tab.setViewPager(pager);
}

class myPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    String[] tabs;

    public myPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        tabs = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabs[position];
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentList.size();
    }
}
```

Home fragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private Toolbar toolbar;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View layout;
        layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_layout, container, false);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) layout.findViewById(R.id.subToolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Dove mangi oggi?");

        return layout;
    }

    public static HomeFragment getInstance(int position) {
        HomeFragment frag = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("position", position);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

}
```

KartFragment:

```
public class KartFragment extends Fragment {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ItemAdapter ad;
    private RecyclerView rv;
    private ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final String SAVELIST = "SAVELIST";


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View layout;


       if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            list = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(SAVELIST);
        } else {
            list = KartObjectClass.listBuilder(10);
        }


        layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);


        toolbar = (Toolbar) layout.findViewById(R.id.subToolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("I tuoi ordini:");


        rv = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.list);


        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        ad = new ItemAdapter(list);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rv.setAdapter(ad);


        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
       outState.putParcelableArrayList(SAVELIST, list);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    }


    public static KartFragment getInstance(int position) {
        KartFragment frag = new KartFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("position", position);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

}
```

Favourite fragment:

```
public class FavouriteFragment extends Fragment {

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View layout = null;
        layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scanner_layout, container, false);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) layout.findViewById(R.id.subToolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("I tuoi preferiti:");
        return layout;
    }

    public static FavouriteFragment getInstance(int position) {
        FavouriteFragment frag = new FavouriteFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("position", position);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'd suggest including the full stack trace, or if one is not available, include the *minimum* source to reproduce the problem.  Nine times out of ten, cutting out extra fragment etc, will reveal the problem - regardless, it will make it easier for others to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the error, the problem was that I had set a recycler view in the homeFragment XML. As I forgot to have it, I didn't call it in the `onCreateView` method and the app was crashing because no adapter was set.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the LayoutManager before you set the Adapter on the RecyclerView.

Comment: unlikely it is not working... same problem. Thanks anyway

Comment: Are you sure you try to fix the correct fragment? ViewPager preloads the next Fragment so the one causing the crash is likely at the position following the one where you are trying to swipe. In your case that would be FavouriteFragment I guess?  Also, please provide the full stacktrace to be sure.

Comment: The error comes up when Itry to swipe frome HomeFragment to KartFragment, I guess It is that one. the problem started when I set the recycler view in the fragment.

Comment: I'm telling you the ViewPager preloads the next Fragment. So the problem is likely in FavouriteFragment. Does it use a RecyclerView too? Unfortunately the stack trace does not mention the Fragment.

Comment: Check the code of FavouriteFragment and make sure the RecyclerView is initialized properly. Make sure the adapter is set last. Also make sure the problem is not in  HomeFragment because it's the one catching  the swipe gesture.

Comment: Nothing working unluckily.. I've tried everything. it's getting frustrating

Comment: Please edit your question and post the code of your first 3 fragments.